# Recovering original class label from Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, keras

I'm new to keras, and have trained a simple sequential model on categorical data. I one hot encoded the labels and trained the model on the one hot encodings. However, when I use predict_classes, I get an array of integers (I'm aware that they represent the index of the most likely class as represented in the softmax output returned by predict), but I have no idea how to map that output back to the original one hot encodings. I can't seem to find an answer online or in the docs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some code. Hot encoding labels and then training on them sounds strange to me. What excacly is your Input, what is your model and what do you want to learn?

Comment: I fixed my problem - but why is one hot encoding labels and training on them odd? I thought naively encoding categorical labels as integers could hurt model performance by implying that an ordered structure to the labels exists where it does not.

Comment: I just thought you are talking about the labels as the thing you want to predict, so nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the values of the array returned by keras.predict map to the likelihood of the one hot encoding with its significant digit at that index (ie prediction[0] represents the likelihood of the label [1, 0, 0, 0], prediction[1] represents the likelihood of the label [0, 1, 0, 0], etc). The value returned by keras.predict_class also maps to the label of the one hot encoding with its significant digit at that index. You can easily move from one hot encoding to keras's encoding with

```
keras_encoding = np.argmax(one_hot_encoding)
```

and from keras's encoding to one hot encoding with

```
one_hot_encoding = np.zeros(len(single_label))
one_hot_encoding[keras_encoding] = 1
```